# Define layout without using Xml

Tags: java, android, eclipse

So instead of using:

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

I want to use something like:

```
setContentView(new SimpleDrawView (this));
```

So I create a new class named `SimpleDrawView` but what do I have to do for it to become an empty layout? Just a plain layout without anything in it.

So, how can I define a layout in java code without using Xml?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by making your `SimpleDrawView` inherit from `View` class or any of its subclasses, Since `setContentView` only accepts a `View`

simply put an `extends View` in `SimpleDrawView` class definition and then use the `setContentView(new SimpleDrawView(this));`